# Chrome fullscreen bug (flowplayer) - sidebar still visible

Tags: css, google-chrome, fullscreen

I have strange bug if my video player goes to fullscreen (Chrome only) - the sidebar will be still visible. I checked the css (it's identicall to the other blocks) but I couldn't find the reason, so I hope maybe you know why.

[image]

The site: https://en.unicstack.com/article/read-id=196

Answer (score 1):

Change z-index of sidebar to -1.
Css:

```
#sidebar {z-index: -1;}
```

Comment: The problem with that: You can't use the sidebar anymore in non-fullscreen mode (because it's behind the site = so it's not clickable).

Comment: Then you have to change #sidebar z-index to -1, when video is in fullscreen mode with flowplayer javascipt api.

Comment: api.on("fullscreen", function (e, api) {
   document.getElementById("sidebar").style.zIndex = "-1"
});

Comment: where "api" is your player. Look here for more info https://flowplayer.org/docs/api.html#events

Comment: `(function($) {  
 
  api.on("fullscreen", function (e, api) { 
 document.getElementById("sidebar").style.zIndex = "-1" 
  })
  
})(jQuery);` - I added this to the end of the flowplayer.min.js file, but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was now able to make it work - thanks to Olga :)

```js
(function($) { // set the "#sidebar" to zIndex "-1" on fullscreen

    
  $(window).load(function() { 
 
 $(".flowplayer").on("fullscreen", function(e, api) {
        document.getElementById("sidebar").style.zIndex = "-1" 
 });
 
 $(".flowplayer").on("fullscreen-exit", function(e, api) {
        document.getElementById("sidebar").style.zIndex = "0" 
 });

  
  });
  
  
})(jQuery);
```

Edit: There some short flicker, if the player goes to fullscreen (sidebar is visible a really short time). Is there a way to make this code load faster?